# Has provisioning storage accounts through resource manager degraded in performance?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I'm publishing an Azure Resource Manager template using the AzureRm Powershell commandlets, and everything seems to be working pretty well. Except when it's provisioning a resource of type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" it is taking over 10 minutes to complete. Is this in line with expectations? I don't recall it taking this long previously.

I'm deploying to East US, with Standard_LRS storage type.

```
    {
      "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[parameters('deployLocation')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('storageName')]"
       },
       "properties": {
         "accountType": "[parameters('storageType')]"
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting question, and I will probably spend a little time getting metrics later!

However, I suspect you are correct but there are reasons that that would be the case.

When you create a Storage Account in Powershell, whether Service or Resource Management, you submit a job to create an account and that is all that needs occur.

When you deploy a template, there are a number of steps that need to be completed. Such as

- Template Validation
- Job ordering / Resolving dependencies (even if there is only a single step, this would be part of the pipeline)
- Comparison with existing infrastructure (because templates are idempotent there needs to be a check of what currently exists)
- creating a deployment job
- the actual deployment

Each step in the pipeline is (very likely) performed through a queue, so even a few seconds for each step to dequeue will add up.

If you enable verbose / debug logging, you will see a lot of this going on (especially with larger templates)

Comment: In my experience, creating a storage account through Resource Manager API (without any templating) is actually quite time consuming though I don't know the reason for that. In fact, there was another similar question asked on Stack Overflow some days ago which also talked about the same issue.

Comment: @GauravMantri Under the covers it would make sense that the ARM API all feed into the same processes. That at some point the API injects a job into the pipeline.

Comment: I think you are correct, I've been getting stuck in a Queue on that step waiting for that to be processed. What's strange was, it was very consistently 10 minutes for the storage account to be created. However, I just tried again for the 8th time in the past two days, and it was 30 seconds (more in line with my experience).

Comment: I think if you're creating a storageAccount with a name that you've used previously *and* doing it right after deleting it, you'll see a delay as there are still cleanup operations taking place.  If you wait a while (e.g. 10-15 mins) or use a unique name then it should finish in that 30 second window.  Is that the behavior you're seeing?